Incorrect Use of Indexing on GCP Datastore
I'm a beginner with Datastore, and I'm having an indexing issue I was hoping y'all could help with. I'm using a google.cloud.nbd model called Program, and I want to check that contact_email is not null and the value for property claimer_digest_email_frequency is among a list of values. That Python code looks like this:
matching_programs_keys = Program.query(
    Program.contact_email != None,
    Program.claimer_digest_email_frequency.IN(possible_values),
).fetch(keys_only=True)

Even though I've indexed our properties in the project I'm using, I'm still running into an indexing error. Any thoughts? Have I created my index correctly for this query? Is something else going wrong?
Index in Google Cloud Datastore UI
Error encountered

Edit: thanks to DazWilkin.
The index.yaml file said
  - kind: Program
    properties:
      - name: contact_email
      - name: claimer_digest_email_frequency

When it should have been:
  - kind: Program
    properties:
      - name: claimer_digest_email_frequency
      - name: contact_email

Turns out the order matters. Check the error message for exactly what order it needs to run that query.

The error suggests that you will need to create the Composite index it describes in order to fulfill your query.

Thanks DazWilkin, that was it. Edited the question with what fixed it.
